# Javascript: Displaying output dependent on which checkedboxes pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web app that will take 2 sets of user input, i.e. Age and Weight and display an outcome dependent on what box is ticked on each.

What is the best way to do this?

I.e. if one age and weight is selected I wish to display one value, but if a different combo is selected I wish to display another?

I ask this as I know it can be done using `multiple if statements`, but I assume there is a better way.

**Current Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Health Calculator</h1>

<p>Select age</p>

<form action="age.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Age" value="under25"> Under 25<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Age" value="over25"> Over 25<br>
 </form>

<p>Select Weight</p>

<form action="weight.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Probability" value="under80"> Under 80kg<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Probability" value="over80"> Over 80kg<br>
</form>

<br>

<button onclick= "analyseHealth"> Analyse health </button> <br>



<script>

function analyseHealth(age, weight){

//LOGIC RELATING TO CHECK BOXES



}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not finished but I think you can guess the rest.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPpjBm

```
function analyseHealth()
{
   var ages = document.getElementsByName('Age');
   var probs = document.getElementsByName('Probability');

  var age = undefined;
  for(var i = 0; i < ages.length; i++)
  {
    if(ages[i].checked)
    {
      age = ages[i].value;
    }
  }

   var probability = undefined;
   for(var i = 0; i < probs.length; i++)
   {
      if(probs[i].checked)
      {
        probability = probs[i].value;
      }
    }
   switch(age){
       case 'under80': break; 
   }
}
```

Better than if might be switch. First you get the checked radio buttons which might be the better choice here.